# How to track down a <pre> message from dpm()

Tags: 7

I have been working on a big project for months, and regularly using the Devel module.

For a while now, an empty message with empty `<pre>` tags has been appearing on user pages for users with access to devel debug info.

I have dragged out all of my custom modules and used notepad++ to "find in files" for "dpm", I have also used grep via ssh to search for "dpm" but it cant find any anywhere!

I also did a SQL search using phpmyadmin, and it does return a result in a BLOB file for a rule. I have been through this rule 5 times, and even exported it to check, but there is no mention of the dpm. However, when I download the BLOB file, there it is!

Scroll right to the end, and this is the only uncommented dpm left on my site.

```
Booking";s:18:"entity_fetched:var";s:15:"booking_fetched";}s:14:" * elementName";s:12:"entity_fetch";}i:1;r:101;}s:7:" * info";a:0:{}s:12:" * predicate";O:14:"RulesCondition":7:{s:9:" * parent";r:102;s:2:"id";N;s:12:" * elementId";N;s:6:"weight";i:0;s:8:"settings";a:2:{s:13:"entity:select";s:17:"list-product:node";s:5:"field";s:23:"field_booking_reference";}s:14:" * elementName";s:16:"entity_has_field";s:9:" * negate";b:0;}}s:2:"id";N;s:12:" * elementId";i:7;s:6:"weight";i:1;s:8:"settings";a:0:{}s:11:" * children";a:1:{i:0;r:100;}s:7:" * info";a:0:{}}s:2:"id";N;s:12:" * elementId";i:8;s:6:"weight";i:0;s:8:"settings";a:0:{}s:11:" * children";a:1:{i:0;O:11:"RulesAction":6:{s:9:" * parent";r:100;s:2:"id";N;s:12:" * elementId";i:10;s:6:"weight";i:0;s:8:"settings";a:3:{s:11:"data:select";s:39:"booking-fetched:field-remaining-balance";s:12:"value:select";s:39:"booking-fetched:field-remaining-balance";s:13:"value:process";O:21:"RulesPHPDataProcessor":2:{s:10:" * setting";a:1:{s:4:"code";s:53:"dpm($invoice_price);
```

Does anyone know how the hell i get rid of it?

Comment: Did you also search for `<pre>` instead of `dpm`?

Comment: Yeah i did, its the same thing. It appears somewhere in the BLOB, but not anywhere in the files. Whats the harm in editing the BLOB? In phpmyadmin there is a note next to it saying dont edit it because its binary?

Comment: I take that back! The pre doesnt show up in the BLOB. only the dpm.

Comment: Any chance you have devel_rules_debug enabled? It has a `dpm` action: https://www.drupal.org/node/1085234

Comment: Actually that would be more structured in the serialized var I think, it's probably not that even if you do have it enabled. The fact that the key is "code" suggests you're using the php filter in the rule somewhere. if the exported rule really doesn't have the dpm in it, export it, delete it, import it, and that should hopefully be that

Comment: Did you also check the templates enabled?

Comment: So i deleted the rule, and flushed caches, ran cron, and the message is still showing. I have run a grep on the entire docroot, and the only instandes of dpm() is where they have been commented out during development. Im at a loss here, it might have to be one of those things you live with, after all, its only the main user who sees it. The downside is that if I disable devel, I get an error on that page because dpm() is not recognised.